# I want a line chart by year, but the code below does not produce same

Tags: r

gapminder %>%
ggplot(aes(x = year, y = gdpPercap )) + geom_line() + theme_bw()

[image]

Comment: You probably need `geom_path` or `geom_smooth`

Comment: try add: `group = country`?

Comment: @Quinten. Please add this as answer! Many thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably want to use `group = country` like this:

```r
library(gapminder)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
gapminder %>% 
  ggplot(aes(x = year, y = gdpPercap, group = country)) + 
  geom_line() + 
  theme_bw()
```

[image]

<sup>Created on 2022-09-29 with [reprex v2.0.2](https://reprex.tidyverse.org)</sup>